# How to find most recent common ancestor (base type) of several types in python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, types, casting

I need to find the last common ancestor of a group of classes so I can return that type.

Context, I'm doing some rather complex meta-programing involving overloading numpy functionality. (don't ask)  I have a variable number of arguments to a function the types of which I have extracted into a set (with some filtering out of irrelevant types) using this information I need to figure out what the furthest down the type tree where all types share the same base type. I have some first pass attempts but I'm getting tripped up by multiple inheritance and the like.

first pass:

```py
def lca_type(types):
    if len(types) == 1:
        return types.pop()
    filtered_types = set()
    for type in types:
        if not any(issubclass(type, x) for x in types):
            filtered_types.add(type)
    if len(filtered_types) == 1:
        return filtered_types.pop()
    # TODO: things get tricky here
```

consider the following class hierarchy:

```py
class A(object):
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
class C(A):
    pass
class D(A):
    pass
class B1(B):
    pass
class B2(B):
    pass
class BC(C, B1):
    pass
class CD(C, D):
    pass
class D1(D):
    pass
class BD(B, D):
    pass
class B1_1(B1):
    pass
```

expected results:

```
lca_type({A,BD}) == A
lca_type({C}) == C
lca_type({B1,B2}) == B
lca_type({{B1_1, D}) == A
lca_type({CD, BD}) == D
lca_type({B1_1, BC}) == B1
```

Comment: There's probably a recursive solution. I agree that multiple inheritance complicates it, you need to do a BFS to find the MRCA along any branch.

Comment: @barmer I think that is true.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `mro` method of each class to get a list of ancestor classes. Map the list of ancestors to `collections.Counter` so that you can use the `&` operator on them to get common ancestors while maintaining the key order, effectively emulating getting the intersection of ordered sets. Then use the `next` function on the sequence of ancestors from the keys of the aggregated `Counter` object to obtain the most recent ancestor:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_
from collections import Counter

def lca_type(classes):
    return next(iter(reduce(and_, (Counter(cls.mro()) for cls in classes))))
```

so that the following expressions will all be `True`:

```
lca_type({A, BD}) == A
lca_type({C}) == C
lca_type({B1, B2}) == B
lca_type({B1_1, D}) == A
lca_type({CD, BD}) == D
lca_type({B1_1, BC}) == B1
lca_type({B1_1, BC, BD}) == B
```

Note that the key order is only maintained for Python 3.7+, so for previous Python versions, you can replace `Counter` with a subclass of `collections.OrderedDict` that reuses the attributes of `Counter` instead:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
import collections

collections.Counter = Counter = type('Counter', (OrderedDict,), dict(vars(Counter)))

def lca_type(classes):
    return next(iter(reduce(and_, (Counter(cls.mro()) for cls in classes))))
```

Comment: [Here's an example](http://ideone.com/ubtsxH) where this `lca_type` implementation fails to recognize the most recent common ancestor.

Comment: It doesn't look like your new implementation does anything to make sure it picks the most recent common ancestor, instead of just any common ancestor.

Comment: It does. By using the `next` function it gets the most recent ancestor from the sequence of keys of the `and`-aggregated `Counter` object. See demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/PleasingAccurateCharmap

Comment: Oh, you're relying on dict ordering. I'm not a fan of implementations that fail silently on a too-old version, but it'll work for 3.7+.

Comment: (You're relying on an undocumented implementation detail of the `Counter` implementation, though. `Counter.__and__` doesn't promise to retain any particular order, because there are two counters with two different orders. It happens to be the case that the implementation retains order from the left Counter, and your code works as long as it retains either Counter's order, but `Counter.__and__` is free to produce an order inconsistent with either parent.)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a backwards-compatible solution. You're right that the fact that the key order from the implementation of the `Counter.__and__` method is maintained is undocumented. I don't see how anyone would modify the module for a worse, less predictable behavior, however. It's certainly up to the OP's discretion to use the undocumented and yet powerful feature of the `Counter` module.

Comment: @user2357112: Technically, both PyPy and CPython provide order-preserving `dict`s as an implementation detail in their 3.6 releases (and no other interpreter has even reached 3.6 last I checked), so you can typically rely on ordering in 3.6+, even if it's not officially a language guarantee before 3.7.

Comment: @blhsing: Side-note: My inclination was to use `mro()` as well (because directly accessing dunder specials is *usually* wrong, and you should be accessing it implicitly in some way), but on checking the docs, the `mro` method is basically a hook for metaclasses to modify the MRO; it's called once, with the results cached in `__mro__` on the class. So for performance, you'd want to do `cls.__mro__` instead of `cls.mro()` so you're not regenerating the MRO when the cached MRO is already available.

Comment: Also, just for fun, since you're using `operator` and `functools` already, you can push almost the entire loop to the C layer with `return next(iter(reduce(and_, map(Counter, map(attrgetter('__mro__'), classes)))))`. I say almost, because `Counter` itself is implemented in Python (though it uses a C accelerator to accelerate counting the input iterable). No, I'm not really trying to claim a pair of `map`s is better than the genexpr, just having fun pushing more work out of the bytecode interpreter. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Agreed, although these days I try to avoid using dunder attributes unless necessary since they often make the code slightly less readable. I also find nesting `map` functions almost always result in slower performance (in addition to lower readability) than using one generator expression, which was why I avoided using `map` here even though using `attrgetter` on classes was my first thought as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take the set of all common ancestors, use a naive minimum algorithm to find the lowest common ancestor, then verify that it's actually most recent:

```
def lca_type(types):
    mros = [t.__mro__ for t in types]
    all_common_ancestors = set(mros[0]).intersection(*mros[1:])

    ancestor_iter = iter(all_common_ancestors)
    candidate = next(ancestor_iter)
    for next_candidate in ancestor_iter:
        if issubclass(next_candidate, candidate):
            candidate = next_candidate

    if all(issubclass(candidate, ancestor) for ancestor in all_common_ancestors):
        return candidate
    else:
        raise ValueError("No unambiguous lowest common ancestor")
```

The use of a naive minimum may look questionable, but it's actually fine, even in multiple inheritance. If there is an unambiguous lowest common ancestor, then it's a subclass of every element of `all_common_ancestors` (including itself), so we'll set `candidate` to the lowest common ancestor when we reach it and then never change `candidate` again. If there is no unambiguous lowest common ancestor, then whatever `candidate` ends up as at the end of the loop, it won't pass the verification check.

The trickier part is dealing with `__subclasscheck__`/`__subclasshook__` overrides. I *think* this implementation should be robust enough to handle *most* common ABC cases, but the entire concept of a lowest common ancestor gets weird when arbitrary `__subclasscheck__` implementations make the graph defined by `issubclass` not even a DAG.

Comment: Not pushing this (`reduce` is often frowned upon), but you *could* replace all the code from the definition of `ancestor_iter` to the end of the `for` loop with `candidate = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x if issubclass(x, y) else y, all_common_ancestors)` (no need to `import` and qualify with `functools` on Python 2). Condensing a stream of values down to a single winner is one of a few canonical use cases for `reduce`, and in this case, it's a big win on verbosity (if not necessarily on readability for those who don't grok `reduce`).